# How to disable shipping checkout fields for WooCommerce booking products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I know that I can automatically disable shipping fields by checking "virtual" on the product submission form - but how could I by default disable shipping fields on the checkout for Woocommerce Booking products (for "booking" product type)?

Comment: Would you send some code, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will disable checkout shipping fields when a specific product type is in cart *(here "booking" product type)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', 'filter_cart_needs_shipping_address_callback' );
function filter_cart_needs_shipping_address_callback( $needs_shipping_address ){
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( $item['data']->is_type('booking') ) {
            $needs_shipping_address = false;
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $needs_shipping_address;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

> **Reminder:** to hide “Ship to a different address” in Woocommerce we just use:
>
> ```
> add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_false');
> ```

Comment: I tried this code but I'm still getting: "No shipping method has been selected. Please double check your address, or contact."

Comment: I would like to disable requirement to select shipping method as well... (for this particular product type)

Comment: @MarkoI. You asked about disabling **shipping checkout fields**, but **not about shipping methods** in your question… so my answer is made for disabling checkout shipping fields. If you want to disable shipping methods, this should be a **new** explicite question that you need to ask (I will answer it, if you notify me here once published).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639470/how-to-disable-requirement-to-select-shipping-method-for-woocommerce-product-typ

Comment: @MarkoI. I have answered your new question… It disable shipping completely (shipping methods and shipping checkout fields too).

Comment: could you please check my other question - not sure what could be the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639007/fatal-error-when-woocommerce-custom-field-is-triggered

Comment: Do you know how to disable the same shipping fields for downloadable products? I tried switching "booking" with "_downloadable" in your code above but it's not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778144/how-to-disable-shipping-checkout-fields-for-downloadable-products-in-woocommerce

Comment: @MarkoI. I have answered your question…