# How to disable shipping completely for a WooCommerce product type?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to disable requirement to select shipping method for a particular product type *(here "booking" product type)* on the checkout. So they should be able to buy product without shipping method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable shipping completely* when a specific product type is in cart you will use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', 'filter_cart_needs_shipping_callback' );
function filter_cart_needs_shipping_callback( $needs_shipping ){

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( $item['data']->is_type('booking') ) {
            $needs_shipping = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $needs_shipping;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

** Shipping methods **and shipping checkout fields too**.*