# Hide Woocommerce shipping method from cart, checkout and order emails (booking project)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am setting up a booking website using Woocommerce. I am using custom post type for this product - 'booking'.

For booking purposes I don't need shipping method (currently it's Free shipping), therefore I need to hide it from the **cart** and **checkout** page as well as **order emails**.

Based of [How to disable shipping completely for a WooCommerce product type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639470/how-to-disable-shipping-completely-for-a-woocommerce-product-type)

We have following code that needs to hide shipping method based on the post type ('booking'):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', 'filter_cart_needs_shipping_callback' );
function filter_cart_needs_shipping_callback( $needs_shipping ){

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( $item['data']->is_type('booking') ) {
            $needs_shipping = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $needs_shipping;
}
```

However, after I insert it in the fuinctions.php file it does not hide the shipping method and at the backend (WP Dashboard) it gives me a critical error:

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null in /nas/content/live/atputarates/wp-content/themes/astra-child/functions.php:32

It is the following line:

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item )
```

In the original post this code is shown as a correct answer. Not sure if code is compatible with the latest Woocommerce version.

Comment: Wrap it into a `!is_admin()` check, so that it does not affect anything while you are viewing the backend? Or test if `WC()` and `WC()->cart` are "truthy" first.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for suggestion, however I forgot to mention that this code also does not hide the shipping method (in the cart, checkout and order emails). So the problem is also at the frontend.