# Disable shipping checkout fields for downloadable products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I know that I can automatically disable shipping fields by checking "virtual" on the product submission form, but how could I by default disable shipping fields for downloadable products on Woocommerce checkout section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `WC_Product` conditional method [`is_downloadable()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_is_downloadable) to target downloadable products in the following 2 cases:

1). Disable checkout shipping fields

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', 'filter_cart_needs_shipping_address_callback' );
function filter_cart_needs_shipping_address_callback( $needs_shipping_address ){
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( $item['data']->is_downloadable() ) {
            $needs_shipping_address = false;
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $needs_shipping_address;
}
```

2). Disable shipping completely (shipping methods and shipping fields)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', 'filter_cart_needs_shipping_address_callback' );
function filter_cart_needs_shipping_address_callback( $needs_shipping ){
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( $item['data']->is_downloadable() ) {
            $needs_shipping = false;
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $needs_shipping;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

> **Reminder:** to hide “Ship to a different address” in Woocommerce we just use:
>
> ```
> add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_false');
> ```