# Disable "Ship to a different address?" enabled by default in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkbox, settings, checkout

I'm using a template for my website, and the default value of "shipping to another address" is set to one. It causes opening a long form.

I have read there's no way to change it by CSS codes, but the information may not be up-to-date. So please check the picture and code, and if there's any way to address the issue, please let me know.

Content Management System: WordPress

[image: screenshot of error]

```html
<input id="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="ship_to_different_address" value="1">
```

I read online there's no way to change it by CSS codes, but the information may not be up-to-date. So please check the picture and code, and if there's any way to address the issue, please let me know.

Comment: This is just a setting in WooCommerce, It's not about coding or CSS. In WooCommerce settings > Shipping > Shipping Options, for **Shipping destination** select "Default to customer billing address" checkbox and save. This will solve your problem. [See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgXrZ.png)

Comment: Thank you Roko, too. It was a great offer and I did not think of it. However, I opened the template in an online JSON reader and it's a lot different than the code I see in my website. I can't handle it.

Comment: To hide shipping addresses definitively, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57637994/how-to-disable-shipping-checkout-fields-for-woocommerce-booking-products/57638669#57638669 or [all that related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address)